# WPF listbox with contextmenu canexecute not called until something selected

Tags: wpf, listbox, contextmenu, commandbinding

I have a ListBox the ItemTemplate bound to an ObservableCollection of my items.
At the moment, I'm trying to implement Cut/Copy/Paste/SelectAll (To keep it short, I'll just show selectall here...)

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="SelectAll" CanExecute="SelectAll_CanExecute" Executed="SelectAll_Executed"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         Background="Transparent" 
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="SelectAll" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                <CheckBox Name="cbEnabled" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

this is the codebehind for canexecute:

```
    private void SelectAll_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = listbox.Items.Count > 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

when I first run the program and right-click in the listbox, the "Select All" context menu is always disabled (and SelectAll_CanExecute is never called) until I select something.
Is there any way to get this to work like it seems it should?
(and without either auto-selecting the first item or making the user have to do it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug as mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bd75a7c-eab4-4f3a-967b-94a9534a7455/why-is-my-contextmenu-item-disabled?forum=wpf). If there is no focused element in the window's main focus scope, the `CanExecute` routing will stop at the `ContextMenu`, so it will not reach to the `CommandBinding` on the Window, **one workaround** is to bind `MenuItem`'s `CommandTarget` to the main window, as following code demonstrates:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="SelectAll"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

**Below is the complete code:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBoxStyle.ListBoxUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="SelectAll" CanExecute="SelectAll_CanExecute" Executed="SelectAll_Executed"/>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" 
             Background="Transparent" 
             SelectionMode="Extended"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="SelectAll"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                        <CheckBox Name="cbEnabled" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Padding="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as reference... I had the same problem using a UserControl. I had too many MenuItems and I also wanted to make sure to not forget that line on new MenuItem.
Then I went for a Style as this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"></Setter>    
        </Style>

...
```

Please, if you ever want to give me a thumbs up... give it to Vinkal who really identify the problem and found the solution. This guy is a genious!!!